# Metric Induced by order of formal power series

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, formal-power-series

In the book I'm following the order of a formal real power series $a=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nx^n$ is defined as: $$o(a)=\begin{cases} \infty, \, \, a=0\\ \min\{n:a_n \neq 0\}, \, \, a \neq 0 \end{cases}$$ I'm asked to prove that $$d(a,b)=2^{-o(a-b)}$$ is a metric in the space of formal power series. I've managed to prove that $d(a,b)=0$ iff $a=b$ and $d(a,b)=d(b,a)$ easily, but now I'm struggling with the triangle inequality.

How should I procede?

Comment: I think $o(a-b)\ge o(b-c)\implies o(a-b)\ge o(a-c)$ can help with the triangle inequality. Along with the tenary property of greater than. For any tow reals x=y, x<y, x>y.

Comment: How can you tell that? Because if $o(a-b)=n$ and $o(b-c)=m$, what's is the relation between $m$ and $o(a-c)$?

Comment: Suppose $m=o(a-b)>n=o(b-c)$ . o(a-b)=m means the coefficients of a and and b agree until the mth power term. o(b-c)=n means b and c agree until the nth power term. Since n<m, than means a agrees with b for the first n terms and b agrees with c for the first n terms, so a agrees with c for at least the first n terms.

Comment: Oh I got it now! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rather big hint is that $d$ is actually an *ultrametric* meaning

$$d(a,c)\le \max(d(a,b),d(b,c))$$

This implies the triangle inequality, and is true of your metric.

Comment: Is that something incredibly obvious that I'm missing, or ... Because I can't really see that.

Comment: Don't worry its not super obvious. Start by first considering the order $o(x+y)$ for two power series $x,y$. Can you relate the order $o(x+y)$ to $o(x)$ and $o(y)$?

Comment: I think so, $o(x+y) \leq o(x)$ and $o(x+y) \leq o(y)$.

Comment: You can't say that in general, for instance if $x,y\in \mathbb{R}[[t]]$ are the power series $x=t-1$ and $y=1$ then $x+y=t$ has order $1$ while $x,y$ have order $0$.

Comment: Suppose $o(x)< o(y)$. What is $o(x+y)$?

Comment: Yes you are right. Sorry.

Comment: If $o(y)>o(x)$ I can say that $o(x+y)>0$

Comment: This looks like a guess to be honest (and it is not correct: take $y=t$ and $x=1$). What is true is that if $o(x)<o(y)$ then the lowest power of $t$ in $x$ still occurs in $x+y$ and is lower than any other, so $o(x+y)=o(x)$. Also consider what $o(x+y)$ can be when $o(x)=o(y)$ and you should be able to conclude that $o(x+y)\le \min(o(x),o(y))$ in general.

Comment: Yes sorry, my previous answer was completely wrong, my head wasn't in place (and for some reason I was thinking of the order as the $\max$ and not the $\min$. In fact, I completely understand your answer! Thank you for your patience!

Comment: Sorry, that should say $o(x+y)\ge \min(o(x),o(y))$.